# How to add the property to the data model in angular, which only used for displaying on the ui list page

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
export class IdentityProvider {
  public id: string;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;
  public provider: string;
  public tenantId: string;
  public clientId: string;
  public clientSecret: string;

  constructor(data?: any) {
    this.id = '';
    this.name = '';
    this.description = '';
    this.provider = '';
    this.tenantId = '';
    this.clientId = '';
    this.clientSecret = '';

    if (!data) {
      // empty constructor
      return;
    }

    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = data.name;
    this.description = data.description;
    this.provider = data.provider;
    this.tenantId = data.tenantId;
    this.clientId = data.clientId;
    this.clientSecret = data.clientSecret;
  }
```

}

Above is my model, provider is the id. getAll api returns IdentityProvider[] and api is not returning the name of the provider.

Name of the provider should be displayed on the list page(I can get the list of the providers at the start of the list page which is a small amount of data upto 10 rows).
What would be the best solution to this using RxJs

current solution :

i have written toData(idps IdentityProvider[], providers: Provider[]) method in the model which compares every id of provider with the provider array and adds new property name. finally returns the list

Comment: Have you tried anytrhing so far ?

Comment: @Nicolas added in the question desc

Comment: Please add the other code which is relevant to this situation, as your question is currently very unclear…

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with RxJS, here is an RxJS technique I used to map a set of products with a category Id to the set of categories to get the category name to display in the UI.

```
  productsWithCategory$ = combineLatest([
    this.products$,
    this.productCategoryService.productCategories$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([products, categories]) =>
      products.map(product => ({
        ...product,
        category: categories.find(c => product.categoryId === c.id).name
      }) as Product)
    )
  );
```

I would assume you could use something similar to map your IdentifyProviders and Providers.

I have a video with more details here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z76QlSpYcck